# Active Directory : Two accounts same password

Tags: passwords, active-directory

Is there a way to have the same password for two accounts.
(Not familiar with AD terms so i m not sure if i use the correct terms).
Thank you

Comment: Are you asking if you can have them be the same, and be linked?  i.e. when you change one, the other changes as well?

Comment: It would be a security hole if you could discover other passwords already in use by others simply by trying to change your own password and getting denied because someone else has used it.You can't so easily limit repeated password changes the way you can with failed login attempts, where you deliberately slow it down to make brute force attacks difficult because they simply take too long.

Comment: I should clarify that even if the disclosure that a password was already in use was accidental (two users both happened to want it and the first one got it), you still wouldn't want that information disclosed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

domain\User1 - can have a password of P@ssw0rd
domain\User2 - can have a password of P@ssw0rd
domain\User3 - can have a password of P@ssw0rd

and so on....

there is no built-in way to prevent users from setting the same password that may exist on another account. It would not be wise to alert if the same password existed on another account as that simply tells a hacker that another account exists on the domain (or a trusted domain) with that password. Now they just have to identify the account.